# Is Gradle used to automate deployment of EAR and WAR files to application servers?

Tags: terminology, deployment, automation, toolchain, gradle

I'm getting a [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45829987/262852) deeper into Gradle and want to further automate the process.  Generally speaking what are the approaches towards interacting with application servers?

I'd want to automate deploying an `EAR`.  Is there even a need, or case to be made, to step out of Gradle for that purpose?

I imagine it's much the same regardless whether it's `EAR` or `WAR` files and regardless of the specific application server -- but I'm using Glassfish.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to deploy faster to server(propably not only Glassfish) you can just write code in gradle to do that. 
Example taken from [here](https://www.schuermann.eu/2013/08/03/gradle-glassfish.html)

```
/**
 *  ~/.gradle/gradle.properties:
 *  glassfishHome=/path/to/glassfish_home
 *
 *  or in Netbeans, right click project, Properties, Manage Build in Tasks, Run
 *  Add line to Arguments: -Dorg.gradle.project.glassfishHome=/path/to/glassfish_home
 *
 *  For more information about Exec tasks see
 *  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html
 */
task run(dependsOn: 'war', type:Exec) {
    workingDir "${glassfishHome}${File.separator}bin"

    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'asadmin.bat'
    } else {
        commandLine "./asadmin"
    }

    args "deploy", "--force=true", "${war.archivePath}"
//from: https://www.schuermann.eu/2013/08/03/gradle-glassfish.html
}
```

In other words just use your asadmin

Comment: I was thinking there might be a plug-in or API to interface with asadmin.  this is not such a typical task?  most use some other approach?

Comment: Usually you will have some kind of CI(like jenkins) which will compile/deploy your code from repository. There are some plugins in gradle, but usually they just deploy to local/integrated glassfish instance. In Maven it is made by normal asadmin too.